# Can this product be written as a summation?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, summation, products

Can I express the product below as a summation?

> $\prod_{i=1}^{30}\prod_{j=1}^{10}\lambda_{ij}^{y_{ij}}$

I am trying to use to rule $\prod_{i=1}^{N}\lambda^{\alpha_i}=\lambda^{\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i}$, however, I cannot figure out how it works when I have a double product.

Comment: It works quite the same. You obtain then a double sum.

Comment: @Logic_Problem_42, but how? I cannot see how it works, since $\lambda$ is not constant for each $i$.

Comment: $\prod_i\prod_j \lambda_{ij}^{y_{iy}}=\exp(\sum_i \sum_j y_{ij}\ln(\lambda_{ij}))$